# Facebook SDK seems that works wrong

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to add in my app "Share of Facebook" button. Here is code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using System;

public class FBManager : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init(Init);
    }

    void Init()
    {
        Debug.Log("initialized");
    }

    public void Share()
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            FB.ShareLink(new Uri("http://www.google.com/"), "google", "google super search engine", null,ShareCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            Login();
        }
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List<string>() { "publish_actions" }, LoginCallback);
    }

    void LoginCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("error: " + result.Error);
        if (result.Error != null)
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("logged? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
            Share();
        }
    }

    void ShareCallback(IShareResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);
        else
            Debug.Log("sharing done");
    }
}
```

In app I have button which calls Share() method if you click on it. And when I run my app in iOS simulator, or in iPhone - it just shows me next picture

[image]

As you see here are no any fields to enter email and password. Here is only one clickable button - "Done", and if I click it - it just returns me in app.

Is anyone knows how do i fix it?

Comment: is this screen shown when calling the LogInWithPublishPermissions?
are you using an account that is neither a developer nor a test user of this fb app?

Comment: probably yes, because I have not logged in before, anyway at the moment I have another one error..

Comment: i don't know why but know all is ok